# Need help in finding running average of key Figure for 9 weeks for time series data

Tags: sql, hana

I have time series table data and I need running average of `Demand` column for 9 running weeks.

[image: [attached is imagee][1].]

Comment: Can you please describe your question properly?

Comment: A running average is typically done using window functions, e.g.: `avg(demand) over (order by ...)`

Comment: This is HANA database which is SQL Compliant , as this is more around SQL so i used HANA tag,  i have Time Series data based on Gregorian calender , which is available at weekly granularity , the column Week1 is Gregorian Calender week number , the week series is week number i just added to show that we have to generate 9 week running average , actually i am unable to get this done with windows functions as we have mix up of Month in 9 week series.AVG(Demand) OVER (PARTITON BY YEAR1,MONTH1) is restricting it to MONTH1, please note RUNNING_AVERAGE is output i want out of Demand column

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your RDBMS has an `avg` function here you go:

```
select avg(demand)
from yourtable
where week_series >= 1 and week_series <= 9;
```

Comment: this will not yield  running average

Comment: @AniruddhaShinde then please define what you mean by "running" average.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following SQL query, this calculates 9 weeks average (actually now weeks but following 9 rows including itself in sorted data according to ROW number column, id)

```
with cte as (
    select
        cast(substring(id,4,length(id)) as integer) as rid,
        id,week1,demand
    from demands
)
select
c.*,
(select sum(t.demand) from cte t where t.rid between c.rid and (8 + c.rid)) as smm
from cte c;
```